# How to make this "Reverse number function work", python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

Reverse a inputted number...

Please help me turn this input number into a defined function that spits out a 
that number in reverse order?  I am trying to make it exist inside a function(N1) with a request for input being inside "def". While the leg work is being done inside the "while" loop and being iterated through until all there is no remainder, and all that is left is the input number to be printed in reverse.

```
def n1(n):
    rev = 0

    n = int(input("Enter number: "))

    while(n>0):

        dig=n%10

        rev=rev*10+dig

        n=n//10

        return print("reverse of the number: ", rev)

n2 = n1

print(n2(n))
```

Comment: What is the problem with it? Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. You should not `return` inside the while loop.

```
def reverse_number(number):
    reversed = 0
    while number > 0:
        number, digit = divmod(number, 10)
        reversed = reversed * 10 + digit
    return reversed

n = int(input("Enter number: "))
print(reverse_number(n))
```

Comment: Really, good!! Is there anyway to put the input statement in the function or do those typically stay outside in such instances?

Comment: Yes you can put the input statement inside the [function](https://realpython.com/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/).

Comment: It is good practice, not to include the input in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the fact, that `str` is a sequence in python, and hence you can treat it as a list of single characters (and hence reverse its order similarly to any list in python):

```py
def revNum(n):
    x=str(abs(n))[::-1]
    res=int(x)*10**(len(x)-len(str(int(x))))
    if(n<0): return -res
    return res
```

Comment: Your code is solid, and your answer is on point, although I am trying to work within "int" in this instance. Thanks =)